# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with an arbitrary number of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a `ConcurrentQueue` that is being populated with an arbitrary number of objects, and I want to process those objects in separate threads.

How do I wait for all queued work items to be finished?  The examples I've seen use a fixed array of `ManualResetEvents`, and then `WaitHandle.WaitAll` for them all to complete.

Do I need to manage the number of threads?  How can I just keep queueing them up, and let the ThreadPool handle how many are running?  There will be many tens of thousands of objects in the queue.

```
foreach (object A in myCollection)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(A.process());
}
// now wait for all threads to finish
```

Or do I have to track all the ManualResetEvents in a list or something, and then WaitAll for all of them to report complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply not queue work items but use the tasks library (System.Threading.Tasks) which gives you a lot more functionality around this, including a replacable scheduler.

Comment: Okay, the Task 1ibrary looks perfect for this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `WaitHandle.WaitAll` is not a very scalable solution because it has a 64 handle limit.

The canonical way to do this when using `QueueUserWorkItem` is to use a `CountdownEvent`. Add a count for each work item and signal when the work item is complete. In the example below you will notice that I treat the main thread as a work item as well to prevent a really subtle race condition that could occur if a work item completes and signals the event before queuing is complete.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
foreach (object A in myCollection) 
{
  var capture = A; // Required to close over the loop variable 
  finished.AddCount(); // Indicate that there is another work item
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      try
      {
        capture.process();
      }
      finally
      {
        finished.Signal(); // Signal work item is complete
      }
    }, null);
} 
finished.Signal(); // Signal queueing is complete
finished.Wait(); // Wait for all work items
```

There are a different ways to accomplish the same basic thing if you decide to use the Task Parallel Library though.

Comment: I went for a Task approach in the end, but thanks for the info on the CountdownEvent - I haven't come across that before.

Answer (score 1):

How about (from 4.0 onwards):

```
Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, a => a.process());
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have over-simplified my example.  Parallel.ForEach is not going to work, as the collection is a Queue that will be changing as the loop is rolling.

Comment: @Cylindric be careful with that; at the moment, your `foreach` could finish long before **any** of the `ThreadPool` threads have been started; meaning: any extra items as side effects of `process()` won't be there yet

Comment: @Cylindric in that case, can you `while(myCollection.Count > 0) Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, a => a.process());` ?